# Memory Leak in LinkedList in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Hey I'm new at this and this is homework i'm working at, when i test the Code with **valgrind** 
it shows me Memory Leak in **Add At Last** Function

```
16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==31597==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31597==    by 0x1093AA: LinkedList::AddAsTail(int) (list.cpp:79)
==31597==    by 0x109A8E: main (list.cpp:266)
```

AddAtLast Function:

```
 void LinkedList::AddAsTail(int data){

    Node *last = new Node;
    last->data = data;
    last->next = NULL;
    // if the linked list is empty then set head = last
    if (this->head == NULL) {
        this->head = last;
    } 
    else { // if the linked list is not empty
        // creates a temp node and sets it to head
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = this->head;
        // uses temp to find the last node
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        // appends the last node with last
        temp->next = last;
    }
    this->length++;

}
```

I've read something about when i create an object with `new` i should use delete to free it
still don't know how exactly to do it.

The Correct Answer is :

```
 void LinkedList::AddAsTail(int data){

    Node *last = new Node;
    last->data = data;
    last->next = NULL;
    // if the linked list is empty then set head = last
    if (this->head == NULL) {
        this->head = last;
    } 
    else { // if the linked list is not empty
        // creates a temp Pointer and sets it to head
        // The bug was here
        Node *temp = head;
        // uses temp to find the last node
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        // appends the last node with last
        temp->next = last;
    }
    this->length++;

}
```

Comment: Your `AddTail` function is naturally expected to `new` exactly one object. The fact that your code contains not one, but two `new`, and creates two objects, would be the first clue to your memory leak. How many `new` statements do you count in your code? Do you expect your `AddTail` to create one, or two objects, potentially? What do you intend to do with the second one?

Comment: You create a new node and assign it to some pointer – just to move that pointer away from that newly created object to the same that head points to. You won't ever get that new node back, so immediate memory leak. Just make the `temp` pointer point to the same object as `head` *without* creating a new object: `Node* temp = head;`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yeah you're right there is no need for the second one

Comment: @Aconcagua Thanks , it Worked But Now i have a memory leak in another function :# i'll update the awnser with the code

Comment: Can you try to figure out and analyze your memory leak in that "another function", first, using the same kind of analysis as I did on the shown code? It is crucial to develop your own basic analytical and debugging skills, if you're serious about learning C++. Immediately running to some web site, every time your program doesn't produce the expected results, is unlikely to result in direct improvement of someone's C++ skills; this is something that everyone must learn on their own.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok i will do that Thanks

Comment: A memory leak is caused by not deleting something that you should delete - the ultimate cause is somewhere in your list code, not necessarily where you add a node. Use pen(cil) and paper and draw your list and what's happening. Compare to what should be happening.